# Efficiently processing large binary files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-data

I'm currently reading binary files that are 150,000 kb each. They contain roughly 3,000 structured binary messages and I'm trying to figure out the quickest way to process them. Out of each message, I only need to actually read about 30 lines of data. These messages have headers that allow me to jump to specific portions of the message and find the data I need.

I'm trying to figure out whether it's more efficient to unpack the entire message (50 kb each) and pull my data from the resulting tuple that includes a lot of data I don't actually need, or would it cost less to use seek to go to each line of data I need for every message and unpack each of those 30 lines? Alternatively, is this something better suited to mmap?

Comment: What do you mean 30 "lines"? The data is binary, so lines don't make much sense. Can you put that in terms of a percentage of each message? Also unless the percentage is near 100% or 0%, you'll probably have to profile to get a useful answer.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, that wasn't clear at all. Thirty 8 byte segments of binary.

Comment: And how are they distributed throughout the message? Are they randomly placed, or all in one region, or something in between?

Comment: They follow a set structure, although, while the messages are consistently sized between messages, they may vary from file to file. My plan had been to read headers for the messages to determine the size and build a format string to unpack the entire message, then pull the data from the tuple. Alternatively, I can use the message headers to find out how many bytes I need to skip to reach the part of the message I want to read and then I can unpack that single piece of binary data to retrieve the variables.

Comment: I'm just not sure if skipping through the message to unpack 30 integers will be slower than a single unpack operation unpacking several hundred integers.

Comment: A single message is fairly large (50Kb), so doing something like memory-mapping the file and then seeking (indexing) to the position of each message is a good idea. But that's only really going to benefit you if the information you want to extract are concentrated in some region of the message. If they're distributed evenly through the message, that won't help much. And it's not several hundred integers, it should be several thousand, right? 50Kb / 8bytes is about 6K integers. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The messages are broken up into segments and the header points to the start of each segment. The one that contains the relevant data is about 30Kb but yes, I'd have to step through them and read each one until I found the data. If I went the unpacking route, I'd have to read each segment and then generate the format string based on the size of each segment. I've been playing with that route and it feels messy.

Comment: So you don't know which segment the data is in, and you'll have to iterate through them to check? Do you have to read through the whole message to know if it's the one you want? Or is that contained in the header somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Seeking, possibly several times, within just 50 kB is probably not worthwhile: system calls are expensive.  Instead, read each message into one `bytes` and use slicing to “seek” to the offsets you need and get the right amount of data.

It may be beneficial to wrap the `bytes` in a `memoryview` to avoid copying, but for small individual reads it probably doesn’t matter much.  If you can use a `memoryview`, definitely try using `mmap`, which exposes a similar interface over the whole file.  If you’re using `struct`, its `unpack_from` can already seek within a `bytes` or an `mmap` without wrapping *or* copying.